# Custom url structure in CPT does not work

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have to have this URL structure: http://url.pl/custompostype/taxonomy/singlepost
I have such, but I also have `404 page instead of post or list of posts`. I know that there is a very popular problem, but all the tips from the Google do not work for me :( I think, that I have to change `'with_front'` into false and it should work? I changed a lot of parameters in multiple ways and it still does not work.

Here is my code:

```
function learning() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Myposttype', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Myposttype', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Myposttype', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Myposttype', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Archiwa', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Atrybuty', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'Wszystkie', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Dodaj nowy post', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Dodaj nowy', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'Nowy', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edytuj', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Zaktualizuj', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'Zobacz', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'Zobacz', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Szukaj', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Obrazek wyróżniający', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Ustaw obrazek wyróżniający', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Usuń obrazek', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Myposttype', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'customtaxonomy'),
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-chat',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'rewrite'   => array('with_front' => false ),
);
register_post_type( 'myposttype', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'learning', 0 );


// Register Custom Taxonomy
function myposttype2() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'CustomTaxonomy', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'CustomTaxonomy', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'CustomTaxonomy', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'Wszystkie', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'Dodaj nowy', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Dodaj nowy', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edytuj', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Zaktualizuj', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'Zobacz', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Oddziel kolejne tagi przecinkami', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Wybierz spośród popularnych', 'text_domain' ),

);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'myposttype/customtaxonomy',
    'with_front'                 => false,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    //'has_archive' => 'myposttype',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
);
register_taxonomy( 'customtaxonomy', array( 'myposttype' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'myposttype2', 0 );
```

Comment: Use filter `post_type_link` i think it should result what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress - 404 error on custom post type single pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766187/wordpress-404-error-on-custom-post-type-single-pages)

Comment: Try adding `'slug' => 'myposttype'` to the `rewrite` array in the `register_post_type()` parameters. And also just after calling `register_post_type()` try adding `flush_rewrite_rules();` Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

And then proceed to follow the instructions provided by others, by visiting the `Permalinks` page in wp-admin to reset them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Please do one thing go to admin dashboard, `Setting->Permalinks` change permalinks to `plain` and `save` it.

And again change permalinks to `Post Name` and save it.

It will resolve 404 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rest the permalinks and also make sure same custom post type slug is not used any where in the website, this may also create the issue.

Add custom taxonomy in url with following way.

Change custom post type rewrite array item with following
`'rewrite'   => array('slug' => '%customtaxonomy%', 'with_front' => false ),`

and then add following filter in theme's functions.php file.

```
 function d_reset_permlinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'myposttype' ){
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'customtaxonomy' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%customtaxonomy%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
     }
   }
    return $post_link;
}
 add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'd_reset_permlinks', 1, 2 );
```

Now reset the permlinks and it will work . you can see its tasted in my local system http://prntscr.com/jnxvyo

Comment: I checked it before writing my post.